# How to remove the white square that appear before the playback of video?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.7

## Goal:

- To remove the white square that appear before the playback of video.

---

### Expected result:

- The white square must not be appeared before the playback of video.

---

### Actual result:

- Showing the white square in bottom-left corner of the screen before playing the video.

---

#### The main.py:

```
class ScreenThree(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScreenThree, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.video1 = Video(source="somevideo.mpg")
        box_layout = BoxLayout()
        self.add_widget(box_layout)
        box_layout.add_widget(self.video1)
        self.video1.opacity = 0

    def on_enter(self):
        self.video1.allow_stretch = True
        self.video1.opacity = 1
        self.video1.state = "play"
```

---

#### The image showing the white square.

[image: the image showing the white square]

---

#### The fullscreen image showing the white square

[image]

---

**Thank you for reading!!!**

Comment: Why no one is answering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can hide that white square by delaying the setting of the `opacity` slightly. Try modifying your `on_enter()` to:

```
def on_enter(self):
    self.video1.allow_stretch = True
    self.video1.state = "play"
    Clock.schedule_once(self.adjust_opacity, 0.1)

def adjust_opacity(self, dt):
    self.video1.opacity = 1
```

This starts the video playing as you already do, but delays changing the opacity for 0.1 seconds. This works for me, but you may miss a tiny part of the beginning of the video.

Comment: Changing the clock schedule will do anything?

Comment: I think that increasing the delay will lessen the chance of seeing the white square, but at the expense of missing more of the beginning of the video.

Comment: Why does the white square occur